# How to fix the jQuery 1.8 “Syntax error, unrecognized expression” error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dependencies

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".user_ava").click(function() {
        $("div:.userMenu",this ).animate({
            height: ["toggle", "swing"],
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, 200, "linear");
    });
});
</script>
```

Error: message ( Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :.userMenu  )

Comment: What's the colon in there for (`$("div:.userMenu",this )`)?

Comment: I don't recognize that selector syntax, what are you trying to select? Did you mean `div.userMenu`?

Comment: @MrOBrian, thanks work perfectly

Comment: FancyBox after opening too leaves for the screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colon in `"div:.userMenu"` is incorrect, jquery does not recognize it.
if you want to select all `<div>` with `userMenu` class the syntax is

```
$("div.userMenu",this );
```

Full script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".user_ava").click(function() {
        $("div.userMenu",this ).animate({ // you had a colon here for some reason
            height: ["toggle", "swing"],
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, 200, "linear");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: IMO this answer would be easier to understand if it had a text portion detailing what was changed instead of only an embedded comment in a bunch of code.

Answer (score 2):

remove the ":" in "div:.userMenu"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".user_ava").click(function() {
        $("div.userMenu",this ).animate({
            height: ["toggle", "swing"],
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, 200, "linear");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

change `div:.userMenu` to `div.userMenu`